# PHP: Add optional curly braces to control structures in existing code

Tags: php, controls, structure, formatter, braces

I used to omit curly braces in PHP whenever they were not necessary, which - with increasing complexity my programs' control flows - has lead to code that is hard to comprehend and impossible to maintain:

    `if (condition) {
        while (condition)
            foreach (x in y) {
               statement;
               statement;
            }
        statement;
    } elseif (condition)
        return value;
    else
        die;`

My aim is to automatically turn that blob into this:

    `if (condition)
    {
        while (condition)
        {
            foreach (x in y)
            {
               statement;
               statement;
            }
        }
        statement;
    }
    elseif (condition)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        die;
    }`

I know there are many discussions here on whether to add optional braces or not, but I could not find an answer to the question how to conveniently add them to existing PHP code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: manually... lesson to learn here is never omit the braces :)

Comment: Configure your IDE Editor format settings and click on format. I think netbeans can do that pretty nicely.

Comment: This is why IDE's were invented: I like vim, but when it comes to code-formatting, IDE's can be quite useful... If you want to do this a bit more _"hard-core"_, the [PEAR code-sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) might be useful?

Comment: Dave: After 10000 lines this will lead to the exact thing I'm trying to avoid: corrupting the control flow.

Thomas Ruiz: Thanks, I'm looking into NetBeans IDE for an appropriate feature. My default IDE (Eclipse) cannot do it AFAIK.

Elias: I tried the sniffer, and it does indeed help me find the "violations", but I cannot find how to configure it to correct them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to build an AST, loop over the tokens, and add the braces in. From that you should be able to save back out the amended source file.

There's also the, excellent, [PHP_Parser library](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) too.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple NetBeans editor macro that does the job reliably, though only semi-automatically:

```
caret-end-line " {" caret-down caret-end-line insert-break "}"
```

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fabien Potencier's [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) and then only use the "braces" fixer, for example as in

`php-cs-fixer fix <directory> --fixers braces`